# Binding when use custom class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

There's a **NSTableView** in my UI which works fine when I use binding (A class mode Array Controller, bind with the table columns.) The problem is I want to implement the **keyDown** and **keyUp** event method when the **TableView** is the first responder.So I create a new class **"Table"** which is the subclass of **NSTableView**. And I set it the custom class for the **NSTableView**. But then the binding didn't work,there's nothing in the **NSTableView**. How can I implement the key event method while using the binding ?

Comment: Which bindings are you using?

Comment: A class mode Array Controller, bind with the table columns.